# Using NoRM to access MongoDB from F#

Tags: f#, mongodb, norm

Testing out NoRM https://github.com/atheken/NoRM from F# and trying to find a nice way to use it. Here is the basic C#:

```
class products
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

using (var c = Mongo.Create("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"))
{
    var col = c.GetCollection<products>();
    var res = col.Find();
    Console.WriteLine(res.Count().ToString());
}
```

This works OK but here is how I access it from F#:

```
type products() = 
    inherit System.Object()

    let mutable id = new ObjectId()
    let mutable _name = ""

    member x._id with get() = id and set(v) = id <- v
    member x.name with get() = _name and set(v) = _name <- v
```

Is there an easier way to create a class or type to pass to a generic method?

Here is how it is called:

```
use db = Mongo.Create("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test")
let col = db.GetCollection<products>()
let count = col.Find() |> Seq.length
printfn "%d" count
```

Comment: RavenDB works well with F#, they have some F# examples in their source tree: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/Samples/Raven.Sample.FSharp/

Comment: Looks interesting but "You can use Raven for free, if your project is Open Source. If you want to use Raven in to build commercial software, you must buy a commercial license." http://www.ravendb.net/licensing

Comment: Worth noting that RavenDB now has a free licence that can be used commercially. It limits the number of available cores though.  See here: https://ravendb.net/buy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty light way to define a class close to your C# definition: it has a default constructor but uses public fields instead of getters and setters which might be a problem (I don't know).

```
type products =
    val mutable _id: ObjectId
    val mutable name: string
    new() = {_id = ObjectId() ; name = ""}
```

or, if you can use default values for your fields (in this case, all null):

```
type products() =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable _id: ObjectId
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable name: string
```

Comment: The succinctness is back! Unfortunately in NoRM it appears to be looking for a property but _id and name get compiled as fields. This does work in mongodb-csharp though.

Comment: :) I was afraid of that; I'm always annoyed when these frameworks don't treat public fields equally to getters, it shouldn't be that much extra effort to support both, and I don't see any philosophical reason not to. Maybe you can make a feature request to NoRM, since they claim to be receptive (and you can point out that their competition supports this).

Comment: i'm giving this as the answer because it was what i was asking, even though there was no after party

Comment: Worth adding that using DataAnnotations in MVC seems to work only on properties and not fields.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a record type?

```
type products = {
    mutable _id : ObjectId
    mutable name : string
    }
```

I don't know if it works, but records are often good when you just need a class that is basically 'a set of fields'.

Comment: I tried this first, but the NoRM driver throws an exception 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

Comment: mongodb-csharp has the same problem, they use Activator.CreateInstance(ClassType, true); which throw the exception above when using records

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, you can try adding a parameter-less constructor to a record. This is definitely a hack - in fact, it is using a bug in the F# compiler - but it may work:

```
type Products = 
  { mutable _id : ObjectId
    mutable name : string }
  // Horrible hack: Add member that looks like constructor 
  member x.``.ctor``() = ()
```

The `member` declaration adds a member with a special .NET name that is used for constructors, so .NET thinks it is a constructor. I'd be very careful about using this, but it may work in your scenario, because the member appears as a constructor via Reflection.

If this is the only way to get succinct type declaration that works with libraries like MongoDB, then it will hopefuly motivate the F# team to solve the problem in the future version of the language (e.g. I could easily imagine some special attribute that would force F# compiler to add parameterless constructor).

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty wild, I had looked around and saw many questions asking whether it was possible to have a parameterless constructor with record types and all said it was impossible...

Comment: But ya know, I think I'd rather see automatic properties implemented for normal reference types before default constructors for record reference types. Indeed, with all the various ways of supposedly being able to defines classes and structs succinctly, I find none is sufficient on it's own and it always ends up requiring the most verbose means to get the job done; I'd really like to see a consistent single way of creating reference and struct types with succinct features implemented within those bounds.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. Looking in reflector the .ctor() method is created, but Activator.CreateInstance(t, false) still throws the exception 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.' I've tried this in a small test app and even t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }); returns null. If however I change product back to a class (not a record) then it works fine. Reflector suggests the main difference is a record is sealed, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: Ah ha, products as class is ".method public specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed" but products as record (with hack) is ".method public instance void .ctor() cil managed" so I am guessing that Activator.CreateInstance is looking for "specialname"?

Comment: Well according to section 10.5.1 of ECMA-335 "An instance constructor shall be an instance (not static or virtual) method, it shall be named .ctor, and marked instance, rtspecialname, and specialname". I'd love to be able to debug further and see exactly what CreateInstance is doing... but looks like your hack won't work unless you can also get the compiler to emit "rtsspecialname" and "specialname".

Comment: @yanta It works in F# Interactive but doesn't work in a compiled form (unfortunatelly).